# MYSQL Select between date breaking on year

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I have created a simple form which users submit. Everything works great but I recently found that the

```
SELECT * FROM `Forms` WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '{$startDate}' AND '{$endDate}'
```

The column `Date` is type `TEXT`. I needed it to be text cause I thought it would be easier to display everything in  `MM/DD/YY` format. Now I dont want to risk changing the data type since the form is working fine.

Example of Date column

```
01-03-2013
01-04-2013
07-25-2012
08-01-2012
08-01-2012
08-01-2012
08-01-2012
```

Ex of working Query

```
SELECT * FROM `Forms` Where `Date` Between '01-08-2012' and '12-12-2012'
```

Ex of not working Query

```
SELECT * FROM `Forms` Where `Date` Between '01-08-2012' and '01-04-2013'
```

Any reason why it would break if the year changes? How can I get it to work even if the year changes.

Comment: since it is text 01-04.... comes before 01-08..... convert it to a date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
SELECT * FROM `Forms` 
WHERE str_to_date(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2012-01-30' AND '2013-09-29'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a145/1)

**EDIT :**

if you want fix your table here how you do

1. Add a new column of the appropriate [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) data type:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `Forms` ADD `new_date` DATE AFTER `Date`;
   ```
2. Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to populate that new column with the dates held in the old column:

   ```
   UPDATE `Forms` SET `new_date` = STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y');
   ```
3. Drop the old column (and, if so desired, rename the new one in its place):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `Forms` DROP `Date`, CHANGE `new_date` `Date` DATE;
   ```
4. Change your application to use this new column.

Comment: edited to show here how it works and if u want to change your table structure.

Comment: Thank you... 

    `SELECT * FROM `Forms` 
WHERE str_to_date(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2012-01-30' AND '2013-09-29'`

Worked like a charm. I will keep the data type change instructions in book mark. 

I m pretty sure everyone guessed I have no knowledge in SQL.. It was pretty dumb not to follow the standard format in SQL table.

Thank you very much guys you saved me hours of headbanging

Answer (score 4):

Because your column is a `TEXT` column MySQL will use an alphabetic compare.

`01-08` comes before `01-04` so it's actually the month part already that breaks.

To fix this, either convert the column to a `DATE` type or reverse the order of the date to `YYYY-MM-DD`, in both cases the `BETWEEN` should function correctly.

Comment: sounds interesting can we do that in the query it self something like

Select * from FORMS where Reverse(Date) between 2012-12-12 and 2013-01-04 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
SELECT * FROM `Forms` Where str_to_date(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') Between '01-08-2012' and '12-12-2012'
```

Comment: Converting the date on the fly is probably not a good idea if you have a large dataset. But this is quick if your dataset is small.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about it breaking then export the database then make the change. You won't get what you expect because it is a TEXT field not a date field. MySQL is sorting per character. As in it is looking at the first character then the next then the next.

Like navnav said it won't break but make a backup just encase.

As for displaying only the date you can explode() on a space to get only the date:

```
<?php

list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $datetime, 2);
echo $date;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from "forms" where Date('column_name') between '' and ''
```